# Browser State - Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a way to detect when my browser is loading and show a loading icon.

Also, is this the correct way to go about it or is there a 'standard' practice to accomplish something like that?

Edit: This functionality will be used for one of my sites during database transactions / table building.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Do you mean when your desktop browser application is loading? Do you mean you have some data coming back from the server and you want to show a loading icon while the communication is happening? Do you mean the DOM is taking a while to build and you want to show a loading message while the DOM is loading?

Comment: Why don't you start the loading icon automatically on page load, chain the success callbacks together using a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and then hide it when the deferred object is resolved [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/). Just a suggestion but it should be easier than keeping up with each resource's load event.

Comment: How is your content being loaded?  Typically those loading icons indicate the wait period for an AJAX request to be processed and received.

Comment: The contented is loaded directly from coldfusion queries which they build tables, graphs, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a slightly different approach to this problem and this is what I came up with.

Code to reset my loading icon when the page is ready

```
$(document ).ready(function() {
  $('#test').hide();  
});
```

The function that shows the loading icon

```
$('.loadState').click(function () {
   $('#test').show();
});
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="test">
     <h3> <i class='icon-spinner icon-spin icon-large'></i> Compiling Requested Data </h3>
</div>
```

And I'm calling the show function my adding this `class='loadState'` on my submit button.

Edit: Cleaned the mixing between js and jQuery code.

Comment: Mixing jQuery and Vanilla?

Comment: @RPM Cleaned the code. Sometimes I do that when I can't remember a method on the fly and then I go back to redo my work.

Answer (score 4):

I like the [JQuery loadmask](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/) plugin for this.  Apply a mask over the element that is waiting to load some stuff (say via AJAX) on page load:

```
$('#containerid').mask("<img src='loadinganim.gif'/> Waiting...");
```

[image: Waiting image]

Then when everything is loaded and the user can interact with the element, remove the mask overlay (typically in a callback for an AJAX call after successful completion):

```
$('#containerid').unmask();
```

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, the [demo page](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) for this plugin doesn't work...

Comment: I was linking to the wrong plugin (with a similar name).  The link should be fixed now.

Comment: Ahh, Nice. I see it now. That's actually pretty cool. Nice find.

Answer (score -1):

Try an onPage load event listener. Im kind of new to js so I may be off a little.